# inheritance from int and increase in python

Tags: python

I try to inherit from `int` and write the `increase()` function for it.

```
import math


class Counter(int):

    def increase(self):
        self += 1
        # it should be less then 2**32
        maximum = math.pow(2, 32)
        if self > maximum:
            self -= maximum



counter = Counter(10)
print counter
counter.increase()
print counter
counter.increase()
print counter
```

ouput:

```
10
10
10
```

It doesn't work! Why and how to write the code?

Comment: Seems like a weird idea to inherit `int`. Why not just have an `int` attribute?

Comment: Also it's a bad idea to compute `maximum` every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do what you are trying to do here since integers are immutable in Python. Once they are created they cannot be changed.

From [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)

> The value of some objects can change. Objects whose value can change are said to be mutable; objects whose value is unchangeable once they are created are called immutable. **...** **An object’s mutability is determined by its type; for instance, numbers, strings and tuples are immutable, while dictionaries and lists are mutable.**

Depending on what you are going to use this for what you could do instead is the following:

```
class Counter(object): # new style object definition.

    def __init__( self, num ):
        self.value = num
        # this is 32bit int max as well, same as pow(2,32) function.
        self.maximum = 0xFFFFFFFF 
    def increase(self):
        self.value += 1

        if self.value > self.maximum:
            self.value -= self.maximum

    def __repr__( self ): # representation function.
        return str(self.value)

    def __str__( self ): # string function
        return str(self.value)

counter = Counter(10)
print counter
counter.increase()
print counter
counter.increase()
print counter
```